# Powershell Winforms - handling window-events

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, powershell, event-handling

Code doesn't work as expected. ShowDialog() is blocking thread. Events aren't handled. How can I make this work? Window has to close after 3 times clicking. Window may or may not run in a separate thread. Mainloop(write-host $x) has to run while window can handle mouseclick-events.

```
function myform{
        $m=0
        $fr = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $ev = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fr -EventName Mouseclick -Action {
            $m++
            if($m -ge 3){
                $fr.Close()
                }
            }
        $fr.Activate()
        $fr.ShowDialog()
    }
    #$myjob = Start-Job $Function:myform
    $myjob
    $x = 0
    myform

    while($x -lt 3){
        $x++
        write-host $x
        Start-Sleep 2
        }
    Stop-Job -id $myjob.id
```

Comment: You need to add a form event. Forms don't sit there waiting for input, your $ev action will only execute once (when the form is displayed).

Comment: I thought Register-ObjectEvent is the proper way of event-handling in PS? It actually does the job, but PS caches the events up till the window is closed.

Comment: Forms have their own event handlers. The easiest way to do what you're trying is simply to move all the code inside the form.